# How to make an emoji-hopping command that sends invite links of participating servers

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an emoji-hopping system for my bot.
But I can't seem to get anything to work, except creating the channel.

**What's meant to happen:**
The server owner/mod is meant to do a command `emojihop` and it creates the channel then a few seconds later post in that channel saying this server has hopped in on the Emoji-Hopping Quest with server invite etc. but the issue is it just creates the channel and if the command is mentioned over and over it creates more channels.

**My Code:**

```
if (command === "emojihop") {

  const logChannel = client.channels.find('name', 'emoji-hop');
  console.log(command)
  if (!logChannel) {

    const invite = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.type !== "category" && c.position === 0).createInvite({
      maxAge: 0
    });
    message.guild.createChannel('emoji-hop', 'text')
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);

    const logChannel = client.channels.find('name', 'emoji-hop');

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()

      .setTimestamp()
      .setTitle(`This Server Has Hopped In On The Emoji-Hopping.`)
      .addField(`Server Name: `, `${message.guild.name}`)
      .addField(`Server ID:`, `${message.guild.id}`)
      .addField(`Server Owner:`, `${message.guild.owner}`)
      .addField(`Server Invite:`, `https://discord.gg/${invite.code}`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setFooter("Emoji-Hopping Quest")
    logChannel.send(embed)

  } else {
    message.channel.send("Channel Exists")
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the channel you have to change a few things. Here is what you should have:

```
message.guild.createChannel('emoji-hop', 'text')
      .then(c=>{
          c.send(richEmbedGoesHere)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
          console.error(err)
      });
```

With this, it will send as soon as the channel is created.

For your other problem, I think I know what you did wrong. Either node or discord changed this to where you can't do `.find('name','emoji-hop')` anymore. You have to do it like this

```
message.guild.channels.find(c=>c.name==="emoji-hop")
```

Tell me if any of this helps! 
Wishing you luck,

Zaedus